# Addressing 'Capture of 'self' with Non-Sendable Type' Warning in Xcode Project with Strict Concurrency Checking

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, concurrency, xcode15

I configured the "**Strict Concurrency Checking**" to "**complete**" within an Xcode project. Upon doing so, I encountered a warning stating `Capture of 'self' with non-sendable type 'ViewA' in a @Sendable closure` within the `didNavigate?()` function. What would be the most effective approach to address this issue? While I am aware that relocating the `buttonAction` closure to the `Button` body can suppress the warning, this is not a viable option as it conflicts with the desired logic and view separation.

```
import SwiftUI

class Navigation {
    static let shared = Navigation()
    var unsendable: Any?
    
    var target: String?
    
    @MainActor
    func navigateTo(_ name: String, completion: () -> Void) {
        // do navigation task ...
        self.target = name
        completion()
    }
}

class UnsendableClass {
    var item: Any?
}

struct ViewA: View {
    var unsendableItem: UnsendableClass?
    var didNavigate: (() -> Void)? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button {
                buttonAction()
            } label: {
                Text("navigate")
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
    
    // MARK: - Actions
    
    func buttonAction() {
        /// very complex and long function
        Task { @MainActor in
            Navigation.shared.navigateTo("new") {
                 didNavigate?()
            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ViewA {
        print("did navigate")
    }
}
```

Comment: It's hard to tell what's appropriate here, because it's not really clear what the `Navigation` class does. Where are its object instantiated? How is that `target` property used?

Comment: The Navigation Class is responsible for changing the tab, pushing and poping view in NavigationStack, and so on. Are you trying to make the `Navigation` class `Sendable`? This can't be an option,  because it has some non-sendable properties. What is your general approach?

Comment: is there any way to make a closure non-sendable?

Comment: In SwiftUI you can use a `@State` struct instead of class and use `.task(id:isRunning)` instead of `Task{}`

Comment: @Amirca "Am [I] trying to make the Navigation class Sendable?" Huh? I'm not trying to do anything, this is your code lol. You haven't really answered my question, how is this `target` used? It's unsynchronized shared mutable state, and since the whole point of the strict concurrency checking is to detect unsynchronized shared mutable state, this is going to trigger a warning.

Comment: @Alexander, The "Target" represents a SwiftUI View, and I've developed a simplified mock-up code using String instead of the View Protocol. Within the navigation flow of UIKit, responsible for pushing and popping, the "Target" is pushed by encapsulating it in a UIHostingController within a ViewController. Consequently, the Target (View) will exclusively be utilized on the main thread and not by any other threads.

Comment: But the `target` is a string... not a view, so I'm not really sure I follow. I assume it's some kind of handle that identifies a view? In any case, since all this view-related stuff is only meant to be happening from the main thread, you don't actually need this object to be shared cross-thread. You should annotate it with `@MainActor`, and that'll solve your issue.