# Strict Concurrency Checking: "Capture of 'self' with non-sendable type '<ViewNameHere>' in a `@Sendable` closure"

Tags: swift, swiftui, concurrency

Considering something like this, with strict concurrency checking set to "complete":

```
@State var isLoading = false

var body: some View {
    if isLoading {
        ProgressView()
    } else {
        Button(action: doSomething) {
            Text("Do something")
        }
    }
}

func doSomething() {
    isLoading = true
    Task {
        try? await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 1_000_000_000)
        // do something async here
        await MainActor.run {
            isLoading = false // << Warning here
        }
    }
}
```

I get this warning: `Capture of 'self' with non-sendable type <ViewNameHere> in a '@Sendable' closure`. I Don't really know what else to do here, I tried a dedicated `Observable` with or without `.task`, but as soon as I reference a value from the view inside a `Task` I get this warning and I don't see a way around it. I also searched around, but other questions (such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77603345/addressing-capture-of-self-with-non-sendable-type-warning-in-xcode-project-w)) don't have an answer at all or something like "it's a bug in version xxx" which I'm not sure if that's still the case.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

When running asynchronous code in a view its best to do it inside a `.task` modifier

```
.task(id: isLoading) {
    guard isLoading else { return }
    try? await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 1_000_000_000)
    isLoading = false
}
```

Comment: I just realised that I tried the `.task` on a `var someView: some View` within the `View` which doesn't work. This way seems to do the trick, thanks :)
So if I want to use an async task to handle the results of a `.dropDestination`, I store the result in a `@State` and then use a `.task(id: dropItems)`?

Comment: That should work.